# Modify PATH internally from with gvim?

Tags: vim, path, environment-variables

I have quite a few tools expected to be used togather with gvim on Windows. Usually the env variable PATH should be set for each tool respectively. Is it possible to  make the modified PATH variable privately visible to gvim itself rather than system-widely visible to all programs?

BR,Ruochen

Comment: It's not possible to give it system wide visibility!  The value of PATH is only relevant to the shell in which it is set, and that can certainly vary with every shell running on the system.

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the PATH directly inside Vim (or your `~/.vimrc`); it will then used for any external command started from it (i.e. `:!` and `:call system()`).

```
:let $PATH .= ':/tmp'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want gvim to run with a modified PATH, set it on the way in.
Instead of just running `gvim`, run:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:$HOME/bin:/bin gvim
```

This assumes you are running a bourne family shell. (not `tcsh` or `csh`)

Comment: Note also that this answer applies to any program run from the shell, not just vim